# Install packages on archlinux from website

Tags: arch-linux

I have archlinux on vbox

1. I download package from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/

   - File like xxx.pkg.tar.xz
2. I moved this file to archlinux

   - How can i install it??
3. Does this file include all the dependencies?  or should I download and move the dependency to the VM too?

Thank

Comment: You will need to untar the file and most probably make and compile the source. There is normally a README in the untarred files or a web site associated with the package giving further installation instructions.

Comment: @RamanSailopal The packages listed on https://www.archlinux.org/packages/ are compiled. 'pacman [...] uses the tar format for packaging. ' see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman

Answer (score 1):

1. `pacman -U xxx.pkg.tar.xz`, see [pacman additional commands](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Additional_commands) on the arch wiki.
2. no you should download packages with pacman: `pacman -S xxx`

If you do not want to connect your vm to the internet you could follow this [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/offline_installation_of_packages).